# What is the use of %4d when enclosed by parentheses?

Tags: c

I have a C Code below,

```
int main (void)
{
    int n = 5;

    printf ("%4d\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the output 5 leading by four spaces.

But what be the code if I want to print "    `(5)`" with four leading spaces (but "   `(21)`" with three leading spaces, or "  `(987)`" with two leading spaces, etc)?

Meanwhile I tried `printf ("%4(d)\n",n);` and `printf ("(%4d)\n",n);` but these twos gave `(d)` and `(    5)` respectively.

Comment: `printf("    (%d)\n", n)`

Comment: There should only be 3 spaces, not 4. `%4d` means that the whole field takes up 4 characters.

Comment: If you want say `(5)` and `(55)` and `(555)` all printed to the same width, you can `sprintf` to a temporary buffer and then `printf` that string with the field width requirement - as answered by @Barmar.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it in two steps. First create a string that contains the number surrounded by parentheses with no padding:

```
char numstr[32];
sprintf(numstr, "(%d)", n);
```

Then print that in a field with padding, using `%s` format.

```
printf("%4s\n", numstr);
```

Comment: Since he expects the number to fit in a 4-digit field, I think it should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your question.**

You have already printout the int value, the “4” tells the `printf` to format the output to a length of 4 characters.

**More detailed information.**

> char n$ : n is the number of the parameter to display using this format
>   specifier, allowing the parameters provided to be output multiple
>   times, using varying format specifiers or in different orders. If any
>   single placeholder specifies a parameter, all the rest of the
>   placeholders MUST also specify a parameter.

**For example**:

```
 printf("%2$d %2$#x; %1$d %1$#x",16,17) produces 17 0x11; 16 0x10.
```

[For more information about the format specifier usage in C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification)

Answer (score 0):

When use %4d you define an output format of printf to a length of 4 characters.